# SQL: count from same table/field, but different values

Tags: sql, subquery

In my database project, I had to build a database regarding some data from the Olympic games.

I have to build the following query as well :

*Compute medal table for the specific Olympic Games supplied by the user. Medal table should contain 
country’s IOC code followed by the number of gold, silver, bronze and total medals. It should first be 
sorted by the number of gold, then silvers and finally bronzes.*

Basically, I have a table `Medals`which contains the medals won by some participants at some Olympic game.

The medals are stored in the following way : "Gold medal", "Silver medal", "Bronze medal" in the `color`field of my table `Medals`.

I tried to use the following query  :

```
SELECT q1.country, q1.name as "Game", q1.cntG, q2.cntS, q3.cntB FROM
(
    SELECT c.countryName as country, g.name as name, count(m.idMedal) as cntG 
    FROM Game g
    INNER JOIN Participant p
    ON p.fkGame = g.idGame
    INNER JOIN Country c
    ON p.fkCountry = c.idCountry
    INNER JOIN Medals m
    ON m.fkMedalist = p.idParticipant
    WHERE
    g.name = "2012 Summer Olympics" 
    AND m.color like '%Gold%'
    GROUP BY c.countryName
    ORDER BY c.countryName, cntG DESC
) as q1,
(
    SELECT c.countryName as country, g.name as name, count(m.idMedal) as cntS 
    FROM Game g
    INNER JOIN Participant p
    ON p.fkGame = g.idGame
    INNER JOIN Country c
    ON p.fkCountry = c.idCountry
    INNER JOIN Medals m
    ON m.fkMedalist = p.idParticipant
    WHERE g.name = "2012 Summer Olympics" 
    AND m.color like '%Silver%'
    GROUP BY c.countryName
    ORDER BY c.countryName, cntS DESC
) as q2,
(
    SELECT c.countryName as country, g.name as name, count(m.idMedal) as cntB 
    FROM Game g
    INNER JOIN Participant p
    ON p.fkGame = g.idGame
    INNER JOIN Country c
    ON p.fkCountry = c.idCountry
    INNER JOIN Medals m
    ON m.fkMedalist = p.idParticipant
    WHERE g.name = "2012 Summer Olympics" 
    AND m.color like '%Bronze%'
    GROUP BY c.countryName
    ORDER BY c.countryName, cntB DESC
) as q3
GROUP BY q1.country
ORDER BY q1.cntG, q2.cntS, q3.cntB DESC
```

Well, it gives me a totally weird result. I know there is something wrong with this query but cannot figure out what it is !

Hope you can help me :)

Thanks

NOTE: I ignored the total number of queries (as asked in the assignement) for the moment. Once i've figured of to build the first part I'll try for the total

Comment: Totally weird in what way ?

Comment: Well, it's late for me, but try adding `WHERE q1.country = q2.country AND q1.country = q3.country` just before `GROUP BY q1.country`. Does it work any better ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to compute the counts in a independent way. Still shows some counts but they are wrong (like US won 2200 Gold medals in some Game). The data in my DB are not the problem

Comment: Did you try my suggestion or are you referring to the results of your original code ?

Comment: @ExpertSystem works like a charm :) thanks ! How could I not think about it hehe... *edit* : I replied before seeing your answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data are not the problem - the fact that you have an implicit cartesian join between each of q1, q2 and q3 *is* a problem. Try:

```
SELECT c.countryName as country, 
       count(case m.idMedal when 'Gold medal' then 1 end) as cntG,
       count(case m.idMedal when 'Silver medal' then 1 end) as cntS,
       count(case m.idMedal when 'Bronze medal' then 1 end) as cntB
FROM Game g
INNER JOIN Participant p ON p.fkGame = g.idGame
INNER JOIN Country c ON p.fkCountry = c.idCountry
INNER JOIN Medals m ON m.fkMedalist = p.idParticipant
WHERE g.name = "2012 Summer Olympics" 
GROUP BY c.countryName
ORDER BY cntG DESC, cntS DESC, cntB DESC
```

Comment: I'm a really big fan of the SUM() trick, as it is less verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry but your query is a real mess. You can't simply join the 3 subqueries that way.

However, you can have what you want in one query. I'll give you the pseudo code and leave you the details :)

```
SELECT
    [countryName],
    SUM(color like '%Gold%') as total_gold,
    SUM(color like '%Silver%') as total_silver,
    SUM(color like '%Bronze%') as total_bronze,
    COUNT(*) as total
FROM Medals
INNER JOIN Participant (...)
INNER JOIN Country (...)
INNER JOIN Game (...)
WHERE (...)
GROUP BY [countryName]
ORDER BY total_gold DESC, total_silver DESC, total_bronze DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of ways to fix or even improve your query, one of which is adding

```
 ...
 WHERE q1.country = q2.country 
   AND q1.country = q3.country
```

(just before `GROUP BY q1.country`).

Another solution would be to JOIN q1, q2 and q3 ON `country`.